# How to display scrollbar inside of treeview control

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, scrollbar

I have many nodes and some of them are under the screen's edge. Tho treeview is scrollable, there is no vertical scrollbar on the right. How can i show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to set the [`Scrollable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.scrollable.aspx) property to `false`? If it is set to `true`, the control should display the scroll bars.

Comment: Thank you..It seems like the problem was with anchors, not in scrollable property(because it was set to True). Now changed the dock setting and everything works just fine

Answer (score 1):

This "bug" can be replicated, but there is a workaround.

I have found that if you place a TreeView within a component, and mark the Scrollable property as "True", then in run time, the component simply "forgets" that the Scrollable property was marked as true.

The workaround is very simple.  To make the TreeView "Scrollable", you must actually add a line of code to make it scrollable, because unfortunately the "bug" in this component is that it forgets.

For example, you must simply add in code something like this

```
tvTreeView.Scrollable = true;
```

This workaround fixes the problem, and the tree view will then properly display its Scroll bar(s).